# How to validate associated models in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello Could please tell me.
How to validate associated models  in cakephp?
i am using multiple model in one controller and controller name is 'AdminsController'.
These are Model in AdminsController

```
$uses=array('index','Static_page_view','Admin','Categories','Products', 'contact','User','Rams');'
```

now i want to validate 'Categories'(Model). i have defined set of validation rules. But not ale to validate. While when i use 'Admin'(MODEL) it works perfectly.

```
<?php        
class AdminsController extends AppController {    

  public $uses=array('index','Static_page_view','Admin','Categories','Products', 'contact','User','Rams'); 

public function index()
    {       
    if(!empty($this->request->data)) //this checks if the form is being submitted and is not empty  
        {


            if($this->Admin->save($this->request->data))//this saves the data from the form   and also return true or false 
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The post was successfully added!');
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
                } 
            else
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The post was not saved, please try again');
                }
```

}

```
public function Add_Category()

{

if(!empty($this->request->data)) //this checks if the form is being submitted and is not empty
{



        if($this->Rams->save($this->request->data))//this saves the data from the form   and also return true or false
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post was successfully added!');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'Add_Category'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post was not saved, please try again');
        }


}
}
    }
```

\app\Model\Admin

```
      <?php
    class Admin extends AppModel {


     public $validate = array( ['Admin'] => array(
            'name'=>array(
                'title_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message'=>'Please Enter your Name!'
                )
                ),
            'email'=>array(
                'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message'=>'Please Enter your Email!'
                )
            ),
            'phone'=>array(
                    'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                            'message'=>'Please Enter your phone!'
                    )
            ),
            'query'=>array(
                    'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                            'message'=>'Please Enter your Query!'
                    )
            )
        ));
    }

\app\Model\categories

<?php 
class Categories extends AppModel { 


 public $validate = array(
        'name'=>array(
            'title_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please Enter your Name!'
            )
            ),
        'email'=>array(
            'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please Enter your Email!'
            )
        ),
        'phone'=>array(
                'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                        'message'=>'Please Enter your phone!'
                )
        ),
        'query'=>array(
                'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                        'message'=>'Please Enter your Query!'
                )
        )
    );
}


    \app\View\admins\index.ctp

<h2>Add a Post</h2>
<?php
echo json_encode($this->validationErrors);

//<!--create the form 2parameter:the post model and the 2nd is the form is submitted to which action-->
echo $this->Form->create('Admin', array('action'=>'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('name');//<!--We have not specified the field so type becomes text as the according to the database field type-->
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('phone');
echo $this->Form->input('query');//<!--We have not specified the field so type becomes textarea as the according to the database field type-->
echo $this->Form->end('Create a Post');//<!--ends the form and create the text on button the same as specified-->
?>

\app\View\admins\category.ctp

<head>
<title>Admin Panel</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<?php echo $this->element("header"); ?>
<div id="content">
<?php echo $this->element("left-content"); ?>
<div id="right-content">
<div id="upper">
<h3>Add SubCategory</h3>
</div><!---upper end--->

<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Admin', array('class' => "righform"));
$options = array(); 
?>
<fieldset class="textbox">
<label class="cate"><span>Main Category :</span>
<select name="parentId">
<?php foreach($name as $row){?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['Categories']['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['Categories']['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</label>
<br /><br /><br />
<label class="cate">
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name'); ?>
<br /><br /><br />
<label class="cate1">
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Description'); ?>
<br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br />

<td><button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button></td>   
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div><!---main content end--->
</div><!----content end---->
<?php echo $this->element("footer"); ?>
</div><!---container end---->
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

if your model are connected by relationship let say Admin has a OnetoOne/manytomany/onetomany relationship to Category

you can validate it by

```
$this->Admin->Category->saveAll(array('validate'=> 'only')); // pass 'only' string not only
```

or if you want to use any model which has no relation to default model then simply first load it on your current controller and then validate it let say category has no relation to current model then simply

```
$this->loadModel('category');
$this->category->set($this->data);
$this->category->saveAll(array('validate'=> 'only'));
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: i don't know whats wrong with me but its seems impossible to validate expect default model.

Comment: problem is that your model is not loaded,first debug your code where you are trying to load model, you'll get a solution from there

Answer (score 0):

you can use Multivalidatable behavior.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model

Comment: soryy This article didnot heapled much more because in this article only one model have been used but in the my case there are multiple model being called.
so please heapled me once again.
Thanks.